# Passing data between two html pages in phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

I'm using phonegap to create mobile app.
I don't want to have everything in one html page so I created few of them. Each one has .js file attached. How can I send data between these html pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most portable and simplest way to do it is to use [localStorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage). There is a bug in Android for passing parameters along in the URL so I don't recommend using that method.

Comment: Do you have any extra information about this bug for Android? Workarounds for Android (or a cross-platform solution)?