# PhoneGap not able to pass a querystring

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have an index.html and edit.html and trying to do the following, but by clicking the second and third link, the emulator showed me an error saying: Application Error, A network error occurred (file://android_asset/www/edit.html?id=2) and (file://android_asset/www/edit.html?id=3)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body   id="stage" class="theme">
    <h1>Welcome to XXX!</h1>

    <a href = "edit.html"> 1</a>
    <a href = "edit.html?id=2"> 2</a>
    <a href = "edit.html?id=3"> 3</a>


  </body>
</html>
```

my edit.html is just a html header and body.

Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap Android Querystring issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594142/phonegap-android-querystring-issue)

Comment: It has been 3 months ago, the bug is still not fixed :(

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't mean that it's a new question. Here's another one where using localStorage is suggested as a workaround, and I think that's probably the best way to go http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419200/368296

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bug in Android not PhoneGap. Go star this Google issue to add your voice:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

In other news we believe we will have a work around in the 1.9.0 release which will be out at the end of the month.